# calculating voltage or current for a plain transistor (no resistor)

Tags: voltage, current, bjt, fet, calculation

the short version of my question is this:  how do you know what the current through a transistor will be if there are no resistors?

I am reading mostly the second edition of the Art of Electronics, and I've read and reread chapters 1-7 over the past couple of years, plus a lot of supplemental things like the Kuphaldt Lessons in Electric Circuits.  Most everything is making sense, but I find that when I'm trying to see how a circuit works by reading the schematic, I get really thrown if I have a transistor (bjt or fet) with no resistor to help determine what the current will be for a given voltage drop, e.g.  Is there a standard rough calculation for this?

The authors actually mention this in part of the discussion, where they say something like "what happens when the emitter resistance approaches zero?" and they introduce the intrinsic emitter resistance.  But if I try to use that alone for calculations, I get something very different from what it says in a simulation on EveryCircuit, e.g.  That modeling app seems to attribute by default a 1-ohm resistance to each terminal of a bjt, but I haven't seen that elsewhere.  Any guidance would be much appreciated!

Well, it took while -- I'm pretty sure my question was inspired by this diagram and by the FET Q1, which the authors state functions pretty much as a current source and biases D1 and R2 (?).  I assume that the purpose is to regulate the current and therefore the zener voltage, correct?  Thanks for the answers on this -- I have been rereading the transistor chapters and realize I was just confused about which element establishes current.

[image]

Comment: A specific example would go a long way in helping nail down the details for you. Hopefully, you'll add that soon.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can only talk about the currents and voltages of a transistor when you put the transistor in the context of a specific circuit. The transistor doesn't create voltage or current itself, but if used correctly the voltage/current at one terminal may be used to control the voltage/current at a second terminal.

Answer (score 1):

A BJT transistor is basically a fancy diode.

If you put 0.5V on it, nothing happens.  If you put 1.0V on it, either it does nothing or it explodes with a bang.  Much like an LED, a transistor is not intended for use without resistors.

The issue is very much like that with beginners who first confront LEDs.  They really, really want the LED to operate without any fancy driver, and without any series resistor.  They want it to be like a resistor, or like an incandescent bulb, where you can just hook it to some battery.  But try that, and you'll end up with a little bag full of fried LEDs.

The best you can do is to build either a common-collector amplifier (with one emitter resistor, nothing else.)  That, or follow the modern philosophy and build a 2-transistor diff amp using an Re and Rc resistor.